# ACF order by date, start from today

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I want to show events, order by date, start from today. For example, I have three events, with start date 2021-10-08, 2021-10-11, 2021-10-15. I want to show first 2021-10-11, next 2021-10-15 and next 2021-10-08.
Have you any idea how to do this? I try this code, but i get first 2021-10-08, next 2021-10-11 and 2021-10-15.

```
                    $the_query = new WP_Query(  array(
                        'post_type'=>'eventdate',
                        'posts_per_page' => -1,
                        'meta_key'  => 'event_start_date',
                        'orderby'=>'meta_value_num',
                        'order' => 'ASC',
                    ));
```

Comment: Can you describe the order using a pattern? Your question is unclear.

Comment: Do you mean to show upcoming events, and then the rest are past events?

Comment: @Zuzan Yes, I want to show all events, but first upcoming events.

Answer (score 0):

Try using descending: `'order' => 'DESC'`?

Descending means: from high to low. The date today is 'higher than yesterday. With that you know it's descending.

Comment: Then I get 2021-10-15, 2021-10-11, 2021-10-08.

Comment: It's a bit tricky, but you can change the date of the post. Change the date it was created/published (windows Publish & Published on: X) and order then?

Comment: I don't want to do it, I will have several dozen events, such changes would be laborious.